# How to display a webpage without using webview in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I like the way webview makes it very easy to load a webpage, though I believe it have limitations.

What I want to do is build an app for my blog. I don't want to use webview  because:

- I don't want it to display the blog header (instead I want the app's Toolbar)
- I want the main activity to be a recyclerview, continuously loading post title, image and summary as the user scrolls down (Facebook and Twitter apps does this).
- I want the app to look quite different from my blog.

If I can achieve all of this with webview, better for me, but how?

I was thinking of fetching the feed of the blog and formatting it with xml.

Due to my naivety in Android development, I might have made some wrong assumptions, please forgive that.

Comment: Start looking for free/opensource android project in Github, java2s and many more for projects like "RSS Feed parser/XML News Reader" this way you will start. Develop some part then ask specific question and it will get resolved this way.

Comment: Thanks, but could you be more specific?

Comment: Did you figure this out and have an answer to post? It's ok to post your own answer if the other doesn't help you enough that you want to accept it, but it's good to accept an answer so other people with the same problem find it (and it will boost your 1 reputation 200% haha)

Answer (score 3):

You're definitely following the correct path with the XML feed, but I still don't think that's optimal.

First to answer whether it can be done with webview: Yes. But I really would discourage that, using non-native applications is messy and if the user really wanted that, they could use their browser.

If you still choose to follow that path you can look at [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html), that would allow you to intercept requests and change css etc. but it's a hack.

To do it with native components like RecyclerView will be much smoother. I would reccomend providing a way to get a JSON feed from your website rather than XML as it uses less data and is much easier to parse with something like GSON and then pass it to your adapter. If you make yourself a JSON option and comment on this answer I can hep you with GSON if it's also new to you. Alternatively, continue with XML and start reading about [parsing xml on android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

Comment: I really prefer the option of native components. I believe I'll have more control over the pages. So how do I go about it?

Comment: Read the parsing xml link to start with

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll read it and come back more questions. *thumbs-Up!*

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON to get your blog posts from your blog.Make like a API which provides all your posts in JSON format.Then Parse the JSON in your native app, convert in to types you need, in case if you want the app to run on offline, you could create a database and store the data there.